# how to read Open Financial Exchange (OFX) file and send to php pages

Tags: php, mysql, ofx

how can i read ofx(Open financial exchange) with php that is with csv format

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
    $row++;
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
    }
}
fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Add the file content. Otherwise use fgets()

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in on line 78 occur this error using https://github.com/asgrim/ofxparser for parse this is ofx file http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-ofxv2/index.html#list1